# Invert the color of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a page that scrolls sideways and I have a floating menu. I want the text in the menu to invert the color that is under it. Is there a way to do that with HTML5, Javascript, and/or jQuery?

**Added:** How would you invert an image when it goes over different parts of the page? CSS?

This is the bit of CSS I use for the menu

```
body{
  background:#000;
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  width:12000px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
ul#banner{
  position: fixed;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 0 30px; padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's likely that for blend modes like this you'll need to use `canvas` for the rendering, although I think I have read little hints about there being blend modes supported in CSS for some browsers. [Some reading here](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/04/04/bringing-blending-to-the-web/).

Comment: @MartyWallace I was wondering if I needed to use a canvas. I want to encourage my users to use chrome so will it work with that?

Comment: Chrome is a good choice if you want support for lots of goodies like this.

Comment: Please *search* first. It was quite easy to find: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/07/17/new-blending-features-in-css/ Please note that this **requires [advanced] CSS3**. JS/jQuery could simulate it *on an element level* by "reading" the background color and then adjusting the foreground color. Canvas can be used but makes the text "not text" and doesn't support blending with background content AFAIK. There might be something possible with SVG as well ..

Comment: i would advise not doing this anyway, as it will be ugly and unreadable on a great many colors (not to mention a complex background—which I assume you have if you want to do this dynamically).

Comment: how about making menu with transparent image(gif or png) and css3 invert filter on it?

Comment: @DeminothBono How do you do that?

Comment: @Eevee It is only black and white

Comment: @b2550 humm.. never mind. I've test it and it doesn't works.

Comment: What do you mean "it's only black and white"? Do you just want your text to be white, or do you want to invert any color?

Comment: @pst I couldn't find it, huh. Anyway, I want to do image negative now.

Comment: @bfavaretto I was just saying that the page only has black and white that the menu would go over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### step1. Get the position of your menu

#### step2. Remove your menu and get an element that is placed on the position

maybe you can use document.elementFromPoint

#### step3. Invert the element's color and apply it on your menu

#### step4. Show your menu again

#### step5. Repeat it whenever you need to change menu's color(scroll, etc.)

Comment: That was kinda what I was thinking. If I can't invert an image I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var color = // color in hex.
color ^ 0xFFFFFF (XOR bit operator) to get it?
```

Comment: But how do I get the color of the page from under it?

Comment: Can we use jQuery('ul#banner').css('background-color') ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test page. 
[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jikeytang/wsnJS/).
inside body can't write width, or will make the page appears the scroll bar.
including the following knowledge point:

1. css cover:

   ```
   .nav .selected .nav-01{background:#f93;}
   .nav .selected .nav-02{background:#3c3;}
   .nav .selected .nav-03{background:#36c;}
   ```
2. jquery plugin:

   ```
   (function($){
     $.fn.extend({
       first: function(){ },
       second: function(){}
     });
   }(jQuery));
   ```
3. jquery call

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#content').scrollPage({
           pTag   : '.list',
           menu   : '.nav',
           speed  : 600
       });
   })
   ```

Comment: This is not what I want. Sorry if I took up some of your time.