# Invert an image based on color under it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a mask (PNG) that I want to invert the color that is under it. It is for a floating menu. I don't want the it to invert all at once, just when it to invert parts based on which parts are under it. Is it possible or do I need to do something else?

Example:
Half the page is black and half is white. The image is over these two halfs. I want the image to invert what is under it so you can see the image

Example:

[image]

I searched around on Google and found nothing.

Comment: I can't understand you. Please show an example

Comment: A diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I will make one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invert the color of text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329817/invert-the-color-of-text)

Comment: @bfavaretto Also, I couldn't add the picture.

Comment: I know, that's why I added it for you.

Comment: I reopened this question on the point that it was never fully answered.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a XNOR operation:

Example 1:

```
Black: #000000
Black: #000000

Result == Black `xnor` Black
       == Black ^ ~Black
       == #000000 ^ #ffffff
       == #ffffff
       == White
```

Example 2:

```
Red:   #ff0000
Black: #000000

Result == Red `xnor` Black
       == Red ^ ~Black
       == #ff0000 ^ #ffffff
       == #00ffff
       == Cyan
```

Comment: Pseudocode: `for every x,y in imagesize: newimage[x,y] = image1[x,y] ^ ~image2[x,y]`

Comment: You calculate the pixel value of the combined image by doing (real code): `newpixel = pixel_a ^ ~pixel_b` for every pixel.

Comment: Wait, so is that javascript? (sorry, I feel so clueless)

Comment: Both `~` and `^` are valid javascript. `0xff0000 ^ ~0x000000` will evaluate to `0x00ffff` in javascript

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will work on it. Now how do you get the current color under it?

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that to do for a website a couple of months ago and i'm telling you, it's a real pain... 
if you take a look at http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/ you might find something that'll suit you, but it takes a lot of tweeking to make it work properly

this .js will transform your png to a canvas image and you might be able to modify the colors dynamically with it

Comment: Thank you, this should work but I can't test it right now. I will mark as answered anyway.